# Инициализация компонента

Tags: c#, winforms, .net

Добрый день.
У меня не получается передать данные между классами в richTextBox и управлять им.
Имеется класс Form1, принадлежащий форме
**Form1.cs**

```
private void Button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    object Item = comboBox2.SelectedItem;
    OperationClient SenderString = new OperationClient();
    string Result = SenderString.TypeWMI(Convert.ToString(Item));
    //richTextBox3.AppendText(Result);
}
```

и

**OperationClient.cs**

```
Form1 ForAcs;
    public OperationClient()
{
    ForAcs = new Form1();
}
public string TypeWMI(string Type)
{
    if (Type == "CIM")
    {
        ForAcs.richTextBox3.AppendText("ok");
    }
    return Type;
}
```

Не происходит передача данных в richTextBox3 и его управление (цвет, размер, границы...).  
Как это реализовать, дайте хотя бы ссылку.

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте [здесь](http://www.cyberforum.ru/windows-forms/thread110436.html)

Comment: При выборе варианта 2.5 Используем свойство 'родитель', пишет, что ссылка не указывает на сам объект, передавать данные у меня получается и получалось, а вот управлять объектами формы из другого класса - нет, там в основном говориться о способах передачи данных.

Comment: У каждого контрола есть модификаторы доступа.